# How can I audit the modules and stage markers in OWIN's authentication pipeline?

Tags: authentication, web-application, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

ASP.NET's OWIN (in MVC4 and Katana) allows for various objects to be added to the HTTP processing pipeline.

I want to ensure that there are

- no rogue Nuget packages
- no hard to find `partial classes` that are buried in source code with a mismatched name
- nor anything else that would alter the desired end-state authentication plan.

Here is a listing of the various locations OWIN middleware can be located

```
public enum PipelineStage
{
    Authenticate = 0,
    PostAuthenticate = 1,
    Authorize = 2,
    PostAuthorize = 3,
    ResolveCache = 4,
    PostResolveCache = 5,
    MapHandler = 6,
    PostMapHandler = 7,
    AcquireState = 8,
    PostAcquireState = 9,
    PreHandlerExecute = 10,
}
```

**Question**

How can I audit/dump the configuration of an ASP.NET MVC / Core application and determine what objects are loaded, and in which order they are processed?